# Layout not refreshing from RecyclerView in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've a `RecyclerView` in a `LinearLayout` which is in a `ScrollView`.

I get the items for the `RecyclerView` from the net so I've to `notifyDataSetChanged`.

This is working - **I get the new data in the Adapter**. But the **view doesn't change**.

*Here the xml like I wrote above:*

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager_featured"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/featured_object_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*when I get the data...:*

```
public void initAdapter(ArrayList<Stream> list) {
    // initializing: passed the streams element
    this.streams.addAll(list);

    // the RecyclerView Adapter
    mBitmovinAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    mLinearLayout.invalidate();
    mRecyclerView.invalidate();
}
```

*and my adapter..:*

```
BitmovinAdapter(ArrayList<Stream> streams) {
    this.mStreams = streams;
}

ArrayList<Stream> mStreams;

class BitmovinHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView title;
    TextView format;
    ImageView poster;

    public BitmovinHolder(final View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        format = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.format);
        poster = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.poster);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BasePlayerActivity.launchPlayerActivity(view.getTag().toString(), title.getText().toString(), 0, MainActivity.debug, view.getContext());
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BitmovinHolder holder, int position) {
    Stream stream = mStreams.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(stream.title);
    holder.format.setText(stream.format);
    Glide.with(holder.poster.getContext()).load(stream.poster).into(holder.poster);
    holder.itemView.setTag(stream.stream);
}

@Override
public BitmovinHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new BitmovinHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mStreams.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the data to adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged.

```
mPagerAdapter.setData(streams);
mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: When you have got new list to display, you have to set it again to the adapter. Only then it can update the views.

Comment: You have just added the new list to list again. But you need to set the now list to the adapter.  write a new method to take list in adapter.  And the write the two lines which i mentioned in activity.  It will work!

Comment: I tested it now with minHeight and I see items... - I want that I does that automatically and with auto height (fit screen)

Answer (score 0):

Try this In RecyclerView 
Add this Method in your RecyclerView.Adapter

```
ArrayList<Stream> list
/*
 * Inserting a new item at the head of the list. This uses a specialized
 * RecyclerView method, notifyItemInserted(), to trigger any enabled item
 * animations in addition to updating the view.
 */
public void addItem(int position) {
    if (position > list.size()) return;
    list.add(position, generateDummyItem());
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}
```

Comment: did you really understand my problem? || if I understand what you mean: that was not my problem

Comment: [Sample for RecyclerView](http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview/) go through this may be your problem get solved.

Comment: link to other comment (this question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917752/layout-not-refreshing-from-recyclerview-in-linearlayout#comment51753878_31917906

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `adapter.clear()` before adding new elements. Then call `adapter.addAll()`.

Comment: After adding the new data did you scroll to end of the list to check new data?

Comment: the recyclerview is empty on launch - so as the viewpager

Comment: link to other comment (this question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917752/layout-not-refreshing-from-recyclerview-in-linearlayout#comment51753878_31917906